# How to expand a row on the click of a Button?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, listview, treeview

I'm using the react-native-nested-list-view library.I was able to construct a tree-view but by default the expand and collapse in the tree view is done on click of the entire row. But my requirement is to expand and collapse on the click of '>' and '\/' buttons respectively. 
library used: "react-native-nested-listview": "^0.8.0".
Please help me with this issue.

```
renderNestedListView = (chapter) => {
        return (
            <NestedListView
                data={chapter}
                getChildrenName={(node) => 'section'}
                onNodePressed={(node) => this.handleNodeClick(node)}
                renderNode={(node, level) => (
                    <NestedRow
                        level={level}
                        style={{ borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 0.5 }}
                        paddingLeftIncrement={20}
                    >

                        <Text>
                            {
                                node['chapterTitle'] === undefined ? readProdDescAndCreateView(node['sectionTitle'])
                                    : node['chapterTitle']
                            }
                            {(node['section'] !== undefined
                                && Object.values(node['section']).length !== 0) && this.getExpandOrCollapse(node)}
                        </Text>
                    </NestedRow>
                )}
            />
        )
```

Comment: can i ask you something? why use this libraries which are not at all stable . you can make something of your own custome component. if you need help i can help you with creating one

Comment: Actually the library works perfectly fine. It is just this one issue. Doing it all over again will consume my time. I had thought about it but the library worked okay. Anyway,Thanks a lot. Can you help me with this library issue?

Comment: can you share an expo link with the code so that i can check there